# Generating a BaseUri

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an mvc application, I have the following code:

```
Uri base = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri;
```

This is present in one of the action methods.

I want to test the action using a test method , so obviously this value will be null ,as I am not calling from a web browser.

Is there any way to set the sample uri in the test methods for

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri
```

.Tried to assign a value but getting a error saying string cant be assigned to it?